# Can this equation be simplified?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can the following equation be simplified?
$$
Z=(1-X)400 + X(-120)
$$

Comment: Yes it can. Big time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can expand (that is, distribute) and combine like-terms:
$$
z = (1-x)400 - x(120)\\
z = 1\cdot 400 - x\cdot 400 - 120x\\
z = 400 - 400x - 120x\\
z = 400 + (-400-120)x\\
z = 400 - 520x
$$
I hope that's clear

Comment: Maybe it is too clear

Comment: @RossMillikan a risk I'm willing to take.  At the very least, this doesn't look like a homework problem

Comment: It's not a Homework Problem. It's a formula I found in a Poker Book Regarding probability. Thanks for the quick replies! I'm still going over your response to make sure I understand it. It's been a while since I've had to do any algebra.

Comment: @JuanVelez note that in the context of probability, if $x$ is the probability of an event, it is common and useful to leave things as a function of $(1-x)$, which naturally corresponds to the probability that said event does not occur.

Comment: Thanks! The book shows the -520 which I had no idea of how they were getting to... But Now I see. And yes the (1-x) is the probability of the even not occurring and X is the percent of time that it does occour! Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: distribute the 400, then combine with the last term.